# How can I use the css from an input tag in an asp button?

Tags: asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello I changed the the html Code of a bootstrap template,

Here is the old line

```
<input type="submit" id="AbteilungSearch" class="form-control" value="Suche starten" style="height:25px;">
```

and here is the new one

```
<asp:button Text="Suche starten" id="AbteilungSearch" cssclass="form-control"  runat="server" style="height:25px;" />
```

Well my problem is that the Form-control does not get used anymore.

Comment: I think CssClass is the control you want to use.